# Memory allocation of a structure / value of a structure

Tags: c, gcc, structure

Can you help me to understand why the value of my `dataStruct` structure isn't the value of one of its members? (As for the `simpleDataStruct` strucure)

I print the value with this line:

```
printf("dataStruct:..............0x%X\r\n", dataStruct);
```

And the result is:

```
dataStruct:..............0x22FE20
```

I use GCC.

My code is:

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef struct Main_SimpleStructData_s
    {
        unsigned char a;
        unsigned char b;
    }
    Main_SimpleStructData_t;

    typedef struct Main_StructuredData_s
    {
        unsigned char  a;
        unsigned char* b;
    }
    Main_StructuredData_t;

    unsigned char localDataA = 0xBE;
    unsigned char localDataB = 0xEF;
    unsigned char localDataC = 0xCA;
    unsigned char localDataD = 0xFE;

    Main_SimpleStructData_t  simpleDataStruct;
    Main_StructuredData_t    dataStruct;

    simpleDataStruct.a = localDataA;
    simpleDataStruct.b = localDataB;

    dataStruct.a    = localDataC;
    dataStruct.b    = &localDataD;

    printf("\r\n");
    printf("simpleDataStruct:........0x%X\r\n", simpleDataStruct);
    printf("Addr simpleDataStruct:   0x%X\r\n", &simpleDataStruct);
    printf("Size simpleDataStruct:   %u\r\n",   (unsigned)sizeof(simpleDataStruct));
    printf("\r\n");
    printf("Addr localDataC:         0x%X\r\n", &localDataC);
    printf("Size localDataC:         %u\r\n",   (unsigned)sizeof(localDataC));
    printf("Addr localDataD:         0x%X\r\n", &localDataD);
    printf("Size localDataD:         %u\r\n",   (unsigned)sizeof(localDataD));
    printf("dataStruct:..............0x%X\r\n", dataStruct);
    printf("dataStruct.a:            0x%X\r\n", dataStruct.a);
    printf("dataStruct.b:            0x%X\r\n", dataStruct.b);
    printf("Addr dataStruct:         0x%X\r\n", &dataStruct);
    printf("Addr dataStruct.a:       0x%X\r\n", &(dataStruct.a));
    printf("Addr dataStruct.b:       0x%X\r\n", &(dataStruct.b));
    printf("Size dataStruct:         %u\r\n",   (unsigned)sizeof(dataStruct));

    return (0);
}
```

And the result is:

```
simpleDataStruct:........0xEFBE
Addr simpleDataStruct:   0x22FE4A
Size simpleDataStruct:   2

Addr localDataC:         0x22FE4D
Size localDataC:         1
Addr localDataD:         0x22FE4C
Size localDataD:         1
dataStruct:..............0x22FE20
dataStruct.a:            0xCA
dataStruct.b:            0x22FE4C
Addr dataStruct:         0x22FE30
Addr dataStruct.a:       0x22FE30
Addr dataStruct.b:       0x22FE38
Size dataStruct:         16
```

In advance, thank you.

Comment: That's a lot of stuff.  Surely not all relevant?  Cut it down to the minimum, and tell us for each line which gives unexpected output, what you think the output should be.

Comment: Undefined behavior for passing an argument to `printf()` that does not match the corresponding conversion specifier. If you enable warnings, `gcc` will probably warn you about it.

Comment: with `%X` printf fetches the value to print from some CPU register while passing `dataStruct` as argument pushes the data on the stack. This is why you don't see any value from the struct. Note that this explanation is platform-dependent, observations may vary on other platforms.

Comment: *Can you help me to understand why the value of my dataStruct structure isn't the value of one of its members?*  That question doesn't make any sense.  It's like asking why your car isn't the same as one of its doors.  A structure is not a simple data type, it simply can't have the same value as a simple data type.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%X` conversion takes an `unsigned int` argument. You incorrectly pass a `struct Main_StructuredData_s`, which is not an `unsigned int`, which is undefined behaviour, so I don't know why you would expect to see something reasonable as the result.

*edit*: As for why the `Main_SimpleStructData_t` appears to "work" by showing its members, the answer is still that it's undefined behaviour and it may do whatever, including the "correct" thing. The underlying reason in this particular case is almost certainly:

1. `printf` tries to read an `unsigned int` argument (because it doesn't know what you actually passed, when you say that you passed an `unsigned int`)
2. The small `Main_SimpleStructData_t` happens to be passed as an argument in the same way as an `unsigned int` would be (on your platform), and the `printf` ends up reading in its members' values.
3. The larger `Main_StructuredData_t` happens to be passed as an argument in a different way (e.g., on the stack instead of in a register) and the `printf` reads some random value instead because the `struct` isn't in the place where the `unsigned int` argument would have been.

Comment: @purJuS That's still undefined behaviour, but in this case it happens to do something reasonable. Probably because both members are `unsigned char` and the size is only 2, and it happens to pass the `struct` of two `char` arguments in a way compatible with passing. The other `struct` has a pointer (`unsigned char *`) which causes the structure be to padded internally to align the pointer correctly, the size is 16, and it ends up being passed as an argument in an incompatible manner. But the only answer that matters is that this is undefined behaviour, and you can't reason about it.

Comment: When I print the `simpleDataStruct` structure, the result is the members values: `simpleDataStruct:........0xEFBE`. I would like to understand why the print result of `dataStruct` isn't the value contained inside its members.

Comment: @purJuS Looking at it the other way, why aren't you surprised that the `simpleDataStruct` is showing the values of its members? Printing that struct as an `unsigned int` is also undefined behaviour in standard C, so the compiler would be free to generate code that formats your hard drive instead. Just because one case of undefined behaviour does something that you (think you) understand, it doesn't mean other cases of undefined behaviour need to do the same.

Comment: @purJuS On the other hand, if you really wish to know why this is happening in this particular case, you could look at the generated assembly code. I believe you will find that the calling convention of your platform is such that the two structures are passed differently (perhaps the small one in a register and the larger one on the stack), but the `printf` trusts you to have passed an `unsigned int` in both cases _in the way that an `unsigned int` would have been passed_, and tries to read that. And it just so happens that the first struct was passed in that same way, and the second wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function printf, the arguments are pushed on the stack.

printf pops the stack when printing out the values from the stack. the stack contains no information about the data type, that is the job for the format specifier.

The format specifier tells printf about the datatypes passed on the stack and then knows the sizes of those arguments, it has otherwise no way of knowing.

printf cannot handle a user-defined struct like that if you give the format specifier %x will just try something but it is undefined behavior. You can write out the address of the struct prefix it with & and or the members of the struct, but not the struct itself.

You can write your own printf function with a custom format specifier that internally prints out the members after passing the struct by value, but as it is now you have not. search for stdarg.h for more info

Comment: On many common platforms not only from the stack, but also from registers (i.e. floating-point values from fp-registers).

Comment: @ctx yes true, was just trying to illustrate a point, that there is no info about the argument types

Answer (score 0):

@EOF, @Ctx, @Anders and @Arkku: Thank you very much for your help. I understand that the problem is between the laptop and my chair ;) I was stupid but now I'm a man :)

To summary, I don't know use correctly the printf function. GCC had been advertised me with the warnings but I didn't read those...

If my simple Main_SimpleStructData_t structure becomes more complicated, the behaviour is the same: Undefined !

```
typedef struct Main_SimpleStructData_s
{
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned int  c;  // Add a little bit complication
    unsigned char b;
}
Main_SimpleStructData_t;
```

The result becomes:

```
simpleDataStruct:......0x22FE20  // Undefined behaviour also !
Addr simpleDataStruct: 0x22FE40
Size simpleDataStruct: 12
```

Comment: Correction: it doesn't "become" undefined behaviour. It already was undefined behaviour when you passed a wrong type of argument, you are just seeing different outcomes. Undefined means "anything may happen", which includes the possibility that it may appear to work just fine. Alternatively, it might print the complete works of Shakespeare or format your hard drive.

Comment: @Arkku +1. Thank you.

Comment: Just to explain the reason of this. At the beginning, I wanted to check the memory allocation of some structures. I was thinking to print the memory addresses was a good solution to represent the memory mapping. Using of the prints function was a mistake. Thank you for the negative remarks, with this the world is better !